# Acronis True Image WD Edition created 1 TB recovery partition after cloning

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

I cloned my old 1 TB HDD to new 2 TB HDD using Acronis True Image WD Edition. I did it in automatic mode. It supposed to be suitable for the most cases.

After clonning I can see that my new HDD contains 1 TB (approximately) partition with transfered data and 1 TB (approximately) recovery partition.

Can I reduce the size of recovery partition and add some to my primary partion? Or can I split 1 TB partition to smaller recovery partition and new data partition?

Can I do anything of above without reinstalling Windows?

I have Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: The best way to clone a drive with Acronis is to create an image of the original drive, boot to the Acronis restoration environment, then restore the image to the new HDD.  By doing that you have more control over the new HDD.

Comment: @Ramhound, automatic mode supposed to do exactly what you are saying.  But it done this incorrectly this time. Seems like It don't like to left the empty (unused) space. That's why it decided to fill the rest 1 TB with recovery partition. Can I reduce recovery partition without cloning again?

Comment: Clone it again, and this time don't use automatic mode. Resize the partitions to what size you want them to be.

Comment: I doubt automatic mode does what I describe, because you made no mention of a .TIB archive being created, in any event the default options clearly are not what you wanted to happen.  You will have to clone the drive again and adjust the settings.  My suggestion avoids the clone process (which has it's downsides which are well documented on the Acronis forums).

Comment: @Ramhound, as I understand from your comment, the simple reduction of recovery partition using diskmgmt.msc or acronis will not work? I should start over again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did everything I needed with AOMEI Partition Assistant Standard. Reduced the size of recovery partition to 1 GB. Created new data partition for files in released part of HDD. No problems.